# AWK: go through the file twice, doing different tasks

Tags: awk

I am processing a fairly big collection of Tweets and I'd like to obtain, for each tweet, its mentions (other user's names, prefixed with an `@`), if the mentioned user is also in the file:

```
users = new Dictionary()
for each line in file:
   username = get_username(line)
   userid   = get_userid(line)
   users.add(key = userid, value = username)
for each line in file:
   mentioned_names = get_mentioned_names(line)
   mentioned_ids = mentioned_names.map(x => if x in users: users[x] else null)
   print "$line | $mentioned_ids"
```

I was already processing the file with GAWK, so instead of processing it again in Python or C I decided to try and add this to my AWK script. However, I can't find a way to make to passes over the same file, executing different code for each one. Most solutions imply calling AWK several times, but then I'd loose the associative array I made in the first pass.

I could do it in very hacky ways (like `cat`'ing the file twice, passing it through `sed` to add a different prefix to all the lines in each `cat`), but I'd like to be able to understand this code in a couple of months without hating myself.

What would be the AWK way to do this?

### PD:

The less terrible way I've found:

```
function rewind(    i)
{
    # from https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Rewind-Function.html
    # shift remaining arguments up
    for (i = ARGC; i > ARGIND; i--)
        ARGV[i] = ARGV[i-1]

    # make sure gawk knows to keep going
    ARGC++

    # make current file next to get done
    ARGV[ARGIND+1] = FILENAME

    # do it
    nextfile
}

BEGIN {
 count = 1;
}

count == 1 {
 # first pass, fills an associative array
}

count == 2 {
 # second pass, uses the array
}

FNR == 30 { 
   # handcoded length, horrible
   # could also be automated calling wc -l, passing as parameter
  if (count == 1) {
        count = 2;
        rewind(1)
    }
}
```

Comment: You could simply specify the filename twice: `awk 'script' file file`?

Comment: then the associative array i'm filling in the first pass isn't available for the second pass, but thanks for the idea.

Comment: yes, the assoc array **will** be available on 2nd pass.

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183428/how-to-run-awk-twice-across-the-same-file

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The idiomatic way to process two separate files, or the same file twice in awk is like this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ 
    # fill associative array 
    next
}
{
    # use the array
}' file1 file2
```

The total record number `NR` is only equal to the record number for the current file `FNR` on the first file. `next` skips the second block for the first file. The second block is then processed for the second file. If `file1` and `file2` are the same file, then this passes through the file twice.