# Awk command to find duplicate records in columns of one file

Tags: awk

I have record.txt file. And the file contains...

```
Danna,20,female,City,80.00
Danna,20,female,City,90.00
Jason,22,male,City,90.00
Jason,22,male,City,80.00
Kelly,20,female,City,89.00
Timmy,21,male,City,88.00
Tom,22,male,City,90.00
```

I only want to check duplicate records for first to fourth column and print the output

Sample output :

```
Danna,20,female,City,80.00
Danna,20,female,City,90.00
Jason,22,male,City,90.00
Jason,22,male,City,80.00
```

I've tried this code to get only the duplicates in column 1 to 4, but I don't know how to print it with column 5

```
awk -F"," '{print $1","$2","$3","$4}' record.txt | sort | uniq -D
```

What I get is

```
Danna,20,female,City
Danna,20,female,City
Jason,22,male,City
Jason,22,male,City
```

What I need to get is this

```
Danna,20,female,City,80.00
Danna,20,female,City,90.00
Jason,22,male,City,90.00
Jason,22,male,City,80.00
```

Comment: What did you try and how did it fail>

Comment: SO is not meant to code for you, but to solve specific coding problems. Try on your side. Once you meet a specific problem, come again and we'll hapilly help you to solve it.

Comment: @Kisses, would there be only 5 fields in the file?

Comment: Yes. There are only 5 fields in the file

Comment: Looping over lines is trivial, as is getting 4 values from columns. You could concatenate all 4 columns to 1 string and check in an awk array if already seen. Ex: make a string of `Danna,20,female,City`.  Your issue will of course be "how to get first value", since it isn't duplicated first time you see it. Maybe loop over lines twice, like [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28544105/awk-go-through-the-file-twice-doing-different-tasks)

Answer (score 2):

You can delve into the `SUBSEP` variable of `awk` and use fields 1-4 as the index of an array to check for duplicates with the `i in array` expression. For example:

```bash
awk -F, '($1,$2,$3,$4) in a {if(a[$1,$2,$3,$4]==1) print rec[$1,$2,$3,$4]; print} {a[$1,$2,$3,$4]++; rec[$1,$2,$3,$4]=$0}' file
```

Where above `a[]` is the array and the `,` is shorthand for the `SUBSEP` variable. The `($1,...$4)` forces evaluation of the combined indexes. The `==1` simply outputs the original in `rec[]` and the duplicate when the first duplicate is found and thereafter only duplicates are output.

**Example Use/Output**

With your example data in `file` you would have:

```
awk -F, '($1,$2,$3,$4) in a {if(a[$1,$2,$3,$4]==1) print rec[$1,$2,$3,$4]; print} {a[$1,$2,$3,$4]++; rec[$1,$2,$3,$4]=$0}' file
Danna,20,female,City,80.00
Danna,20,female,City,90.00
Jason,22,male,City,90.00
Jason,22,male,City,80.00
```

There are many, many ways you can *skin-this-cat* in `awk`. You can also use the `! ($1,$2,$3,$4) in a` expression to find records not duplicated with a little rearrangement.

Answer (score 2):

You could keep track of the first occurrence and check for a duplicate. If it is a duplicate, then print the first occurrence and the current line.

```
awk -F, '{
  key = $1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4
  if (a[key]++) {
    if (key in b) { print b[key]; delete b[key] }
    print $0
  } else { 
    b[key] = $0 
  }
}' file
```

Output

```
Danna,20,female,City,80.00
Danna,20,female,City,90.00
Jason,22,male,City,90.00
Jason,22,male,City,80.00
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
{
    key = $1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4

    if ( key in first ) {
        print first[key] $0
        first[key] = ""
    }
    else {
        first[key] = $0 ORS
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk record.txt
Danna,20,female,City,80.00
Danna,20,female,City,90.00
Jason,22,male,City,90.00
Jason,22,male,City,80.00
```

Comment: Ha! That is pretty cool printing the empty string. I was looking for a solution like that, but you are just a guru :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` :

script.awk

```
BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}

{
    k=$1 OFS $2 OFS $3 OFS $4
    a[k] = k in a ? a[k] OFS $5 : $5
}

END{for(key in a) if(split(a[key], b, OFS)>1) for (i in b) print key, b[i]}
```

- `BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}` set field separator `FS` and output field separator `OFS` to `,`
- `k=$1 OFS $2 OFS $3 OFS $4` create associative key for array next line
- `a[k] = k in a ? a[k] OFS $5 : $5` array `a` with key `k` take value `a[k] OFS $5` if the key `k` is already in `a`, otherwise take value `$5`
- `END{}` at the end of the last file
- `for(key in a)` for each value in `a`
- `if(split(a[key], b, OFS)>1)` if the returned value of [split](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) is more than 1

Answer (score 0):

With `awk` multidimensional array, using the first 4 fields as a *key* and the last field - as a value:

```
awk '{ last=$NF; $NF=""; size=length(a[$0]); a[$0][size++]=last }
     END{ for (i in a) { 
             if (length(a[i]) == 1) continue; # skip unique lines
             for(j in a[i]) print i""a[i][j]
          }
     }' FS=, OFS=, test.txt
```

---

```
Jason,22,male,City,90.00
Jason,22,male,City,80.00
Danna,20,female,City,80.00
Danna,20,female,City,90.00
```

Comment: I don't doubt your solution, but would that not force all file (first 4 fields) to be in memory, including unique lines ? Would it be beneficial to store just duplicates and run over file x2 ? Just curious

Comment: @MyICQ, "to store just duplicates" - how can you know if some is duplicated without scanning to the end if say one record is the 1st line and its duplicate is the last line ?

Comment: Hard to know without running over the file multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Ruby:

```
ruby -lne 'BEGIN{lines=Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }}
lines[$_.split(/,/)[0..3]]<<$_
END{lines.each{|k,v| puts v if v.length>1}}' file
```

You can also do a two pass awk so that the entire file does not need to be in memory (all the unique keys would be in memory):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
{key=$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4}
FNR==NR {cnt[key]++; next}
cnt[key]>1' file file
```

Or sorted if you want lines that are not together to be printed together:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
{key=$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4}
FNR==NR {cnt[key]++; next}
cnt[key]>1' file <(sort -t, -s -k 1,4 file)
```

Or if you are short on memory, use the Unix tools (which are more optimized for memory use) to pre-select duplicates and use awk to print them:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
{key=$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4}
FNR==NR{seen[key]; next}
key in seen
' <(cut -d , -f 1-4 file | uniq -d) file
```

Alternatively, you can use `grep` with fixed strings to find the duplicates:

```
grep -F -f <(cut -d , -f 1-4 file | uniq -d ) file
```

Any of those print:

```
Danna,20,female,City,80.00
Danna,20,female,City,90.00
Jason,22,male,City,90.00
Jason,22,male,City,80.00
```