# Awk command to get unique lines in a file with multiple column

Tags: awk

I am trying to get the unique lines in a file with multiple columns.

My file "file.txt" contains sample record below

```
20230830,52678,004,Apple,21
20230830,52678,004,Apple,20
20230830,52678,004,Apple,19
20230831,47689,001,Orange,15
20230901,47620,002,Grape,29
```

My desired output is to print only uniques lines from column 1 to 4. Regardless of the value on their column 5

```
20230831,47689,001,Orange,15
20230901,47620,002,Grape,29
```

I tried using sed to add a unique separator between columns 1-4 and column 5

And then I use awk command to get unique lines from col 1-4

```
sed 's/,/|/4' file.txt | awk -F"|" '{arr[$1]++} END{for(i in arr) if(arr[i]==1) print $0}'
```

With this code, it works with small set of data but when I use in a file with 1000 lines, I get...

```
20230831,47689,001,Orange,15
20230831,47689,001,Orange,15
20230831,47689,001,Orange,15
20230831,47689,001,Orange,15
...
```

unique values keeps on comming. They are duplicating. Seems like I'm only getting one unique line and it's keeps duplicating.

Can you help me if there's something wrong with my code?

I am expecting to print only unique lines like this

```
20230831,47689,001,Orange,15
20230901,47620,002,Grape,29
```

Comment: What part of your code is supposed to eliminate duplicates?

Comment: @markp-fuso I've edited the code. You can try it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to use `sed` to convert the field delimiter from `,` to `|` since `awk` is able to parse the file on `,`.

One `awk` idea:

```
awk  '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
      { key = $1 OFS $2 OFS $3 OFS $4
        lines[key]=$5
        counts[key]++
      }
END   { for (i in counts) 
            if (counts[i]==1)                # unique if count == 1
               print i,lines[i]
      }
' file.txt
```

This generates:

```
20230901,47620,002,Grape,29
20230831,47689,001,Orange,15
```

**NOTE:** the order in which array indices is processed is not guaranteed; if the output must be sorted in a specific order we could add more code

---

re: OP's comment: *`I just need to make it in one line.`* A couple options come to mind:

Jam current code into one line, eg:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} {key = $1 OFS $2 OFS $3 OFS $4;lines[key]=$5;counts[key]++} END {for (i in counts) if (counts[i]==1) print i,lines[i]}' file.txt
```

Place the `awk` code into a separate file (eg, `key.awk`) then reference the file in the `awk` invocation, eg:

```
$ cat key.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
      { key = $1 OFS $2 OFS $3 OFS $4
        lines[key]=$5
        counts[key]++
      }
END   { for (i in counts) 
            if (counts[i]==1)
               print i,lines[i]
      }

$ awk -f key.awk file.txt
20230901,47620,002,Grape,29
20230831,47689,001,Orange,15
```

Comment: Would there be a little change in the your code if I want to reverse the logic? Say I want to get the duplicates only now.

Comment: change `if (counts[i]==1)` to `if (counts[i]>1)`

Comment: I did try that one but, It only prints duplicate line , one for each group. And now I'm stuck

Comment: I want to print all duplicate lines

Comment: ah, yeah, that's right ... need to store multiple rows; at this point you're modifying the requirements of the original question; [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478) are frowned upon; the suggested approach is to take the answer(s) you've received so far, see if you can modify the answer(s) to address the new requirement and if you run into issues then ask a new question

Comment: @Candy a recent [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77021167) that may be of interest

Answer (score 4):

```
$ awk -F'[^,]*$' 'FNR==NR{cnt[$1]++; next} cnt[$1]==1' inputfile inputfile
20230831,47689,001,Orange,15
20230901,47620,002,Grape,29
```

As Ed Morton mentioned in the comment, the last field is the FS `-F'[^,]*$'`, so we can use the rest (from the begining to the last `,`) as key `$1`

In the first processing we count the key `cnt[$1]++`

In the second one we look for `cnt[$1]==1` to get the unique keys

Comment: I like the concept of processing the file twice. Except the key is the concatenation of the first 4 fields.

Comment: @glennjackman ufopilot is using the whole 5th field as the FS so `$1` in the script **is** the concatenation of the first 4 `,`-separated fields. Cute.

Comment: @ufopilot I do like that idea you used of setting FS in a way that it'd match the last field to isolate the first 4 fields to use as a key and obviously it can be expanded to `-F'(,[^,]*){n}$'` to isolate the first `NF-n` fields (`n` can even be calculated in the script), I don't think I've seen that before and may have to adopt it for similar problems in future. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This Unix pipe will identify lines in your file that are duplicates based on the first 4 fields:

```
$ cut -d, -f 1-4 file | uniq -d
20230830,52678,004,Apple
```

You can then use `grep` to inverse that match so duplicates are skipped:

```
$ grep -vF -f <(cut -d, -f 1-4 file | uniq -d) file
```

Prints:

```
20230831,47689,001,Orange,15
20230901,47620,002,Grape,29
```

The advantage here is lower memory requirement since you do not have to hold the whole file in memory.

---

Ed Morton brings up legit point that the first four columns of `a,b,c,d,e` as a fixed string might match `Xa,b,c,d` in grep.

To solve this, use awk instead of grep:

```
awk -F, '{k=$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4} FNR==NR{d[k]; next} !(k in d)' <(cut -d , -f 1-4 file | uniq -d ) file
```

This does have the advantage of only holding the dups rather than the entire file (if you are using a Rasberry Pi) but in most environments use awk alone.

Comment: That will fail when the first 4 fields are a subset of a different 4 fields, e.g. if `a,b,c,d,e` and `Xa,b,c,dY,e` both exist in the input. It'll also fail if the input can contain regexp metachars, e.g. if `a,.*,c,d,e` exists in the input. Unfortunately you can't solve those problems without introducing a call to sed or similar to transform the `cut | uniq` output before running `grep` using it.

Comment: The `grep -F` command is for fixed strings so metachar and substrings are ignored, no?

Comment: `grep -F` would solve the metachar problem but not the substrings one. You could use `sed` to provide anchors around the `cut | uniq` output to solve the substring problem but then you'd need to remove `-F` and then you'd have the metachars problem (which you could do more sed escaping to solve). With different data you could use `-Fx` to solve both of those problems but that won't work in this case since they need to just match part of the line.

Comment: Another substrings variant failure case would be if `a,b,c,d,e` and `x,a,b,c,d` both existed in the input and the `cut | uniq` output `a,b,c,d` as then `grep` would incorrectly match that to the `x,a,b,c,d` line as well as the desired line.

Comment: Then `cut -d , -f 1-4 file | uniq -d  | sed 's/$/,/'` makes it the first four fields. With input of `a,b,c,d,e` you would then have `a,b,c,d,` and anything other than the first four fields cannot match.

Comment: Right but then you'd still have `a,b,c,d,e` vs `Xa,b,c,d,e` to deal with. That was the point of [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77024031/awk-command-to-get-unique-lines-in-a-file-with-multiple-column/77024521?noredirect=1#comment135798483_77024521) - you need to introduce 1 or more calls to `sed` or similar to make this approach work robustly.

Comment: Fair enough. Use awk instead of grep. See edit.

Answer (score 1):

Awk can solve your problem alone:

```
kent$ awk -F, '{k=$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4; a[k]++; b[k]=$0}
               END{for(x in a) if(a[x]==1)print b[x]}' file
20230901,47620,002,Grape,29
20230831,47689,001,Orange,15
```

Answer (score 0):

> something wrong with my code?

`$0` used inside `END`'s action denotes last line, therefore

```
awk 'END{print $0}' file.txt
```

will give same output as

```
tail --lines=1 file.txt
```

Comment: The value of `$0` inside an `END` section is undefined by POSIX so it can have different values in different awk variants or even different values in different versions of the same awk variant and it could have a different value in the next release than it does today for any given awk, e.g. it might contain the last record read or it might be null.