# creating table in github issues using gh cli

Tags: bash, github-cli

I am working with bash and gh cli to create a table for a summarized report that goes into a newly created issue. I am stuck on 2 problems:

1. I want the table to look like a markdown table, likewise:

| Severity | Type | Issue URL |
| --- | --- | --- |

But, the special characters do not turn into a table in the issue body. instead I get the raw input. maybe it is because I used `<br>` to go down a line? `<br>` was the only thing that worked, `\n` `\n\r` and other options didn't do it. This is a screenshot of the issue created:
[image]
2. I have to run over many scans and I want to gather each alert severity into a group and at the end of the code to append them all together for better readability. My idea was that by knowing what is the `SEVERITY` I'll append it into the proper `*_alerts` var. I need help making these lines functional:

```sh
"${SEVERITY}_Alerts"="${${SEVERITY}_Alerts} | $SEVERITY | $alertType | URL |<br>"
REPORT="${REPORT}${High_Alerts}${Medium_Alerts}${Low_Alerts}${Informational_Alerts}"
```

For a better context, this is what I came up with so far:

```sh
SEVERITY="High"
High_Alerts=''
Medium_Alerts=''
Low_Alerts=''
Informational_Alerts=''
REPORT=$"###Unified zap-scan report ran at $(date) <br><br> | Severity | Type | Issue URL | <br> | ----------- | ----------- | ----------- |<br>"
for ((i = 0; i < ${#BODY[@]}; i++)); do
  line=${BODY[$i]}
  if [[ $line =~ "Alert\nAlert" ]]; then
    line=${line##*#}
    line=${line%%A*}
    SEVERITY=$line
    i=$i+1
    line=${BODY[$i]}
    alertType="${line%%\\*}"
    i=$i+2
    REPORT=$"${REPORT} | $SEVERITY | ${alertType} | URL |<br>"
    #"${SEVERITY}_Alerts"="${${SEVERITY}_Alerts} | $SEVERITY | $alertType | URL |<br>"
  elif [[ $line =~ "\nAlert" ]]; then
    i=$i+1
    line=${BODY[$i]}
    alertType="${line%%\\*}"
    i=$i+2
    REPORT=$"${REPORT} | $SEVERITY | ${alertType} | URL |<br>"
    #"${SEVERITY}_Alerts"="${${SEVERITY}_Alerts} | $SEVERITY | $alertType | URL |<br>"
  fi
done
#REPORT="${REPORT}${High_Alerts}${Medium_Alerts}${Low_Alerts}${Informational_Alerts}"
```

## p.s.

the command to create the issue works perfect, it's the input to the body of the issue that is wrong.

Comment: There are two questions in here and I think both are duplicates. First, `"${SEVERITY}_Alerts"=...` would need a `declare` or `eval` to work. Have you considered using associative arrays instead? See [Dynamic variable names in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16553089/6770384). Second, to print an aligned table use `printf` or `column -t`. See [How can I align the columns of tables in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12768907/6770384).

Comment: If you can point me to a link or an example, I'll try it. I just went with my basic knowledge in bash.

Comment: I am not trying to align the table. I am trying to make into a markdown table. I'll update the post with the intended design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For the table problem, I changed any `<br>` into `$'\r\n'` accordingly.
2. When collecting info using the GH-CLI, it will come back as JSON and as such, you need to use `jq` to query and get the value itself. On the same note, the value will be with double quotes and therefore I used substitution operators as such:

```sh
  URL=${URL%\"} #remove last double quote
  URL=${URL#\"} #remove first double quote
```

3. As @Socowi mentioned in the comments, the best way to solve the array problem is associative arrays. here's a very good [blog post](https://www.artificialworlds.net/blog/2012/10/17/bash-associative-array-examples/) that helped me

### p.s.

Those double quotes broke the symlinks I tried to create so better watch out from them