# How to create a Table from my arrays in BASH

Tags: bash, format, printf

I have a couple of arrays  that contain strings that are kinda long so lets say I will use different ones just for example:

```
cars=("Toyota" "BMW" "Kia")

colors=("red" "blue" "green")

transmission=("manual" "manual" "automatic")
```

and I want to have something like this

```
| Cars        | Colors      | Transmission|
| ----------- | ----------- | ----------- |
| Toyota      | red         | manual      |
| BMW         | blue        | manual      |
| Kia         | green       | automatic   |
```

What is the smartest way to do that? Preferably without using third party tools.

Comment: It can help u: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49180405/14821847

Comment: Define "third party tools"

Comment: I might've not been clear enough with that statement. I meant to say that preferably to use tools that are build-in linux I guess. I am going to execute a script that is on a system where installing unconfirmed software/tools is not permitted.

Answer (score 2):

This will get you part of the way there:

```sh
paste <(printf '%s\n' Cars "${cars[@]}") \
      <(printf '%s\n' Colors "${colors[@]}") \
      <(printf '%s\n' Transmission "${transmission[@]}") \
| column -ts $'\t'
```